# If LEFT JOIN doesn't exist then ignore

Tags: mysql

Not all `child` rows have a `parent`.  The `child` rows that have a `parent` should only be fetched if `parent.deleted='0'`

If `LEFT JOIN content as parent` doesn't exist, how do i ignore `parent.deleted='0'` for that row?

```sql
SELECT child.* FROM `content` child LEFT JOIN 
content parent on parent.id=child.parentid AND child.submittype='2' WHERE child.username=? 
AND child.deleted='0' AND parent.deleted='0' 
ORDER BY child.id DESC LIMIT 12
```

How do i do this? I put `parent.deleted='0'` in the WHERE CLAUSE but this would only work if `parent` row existed.

Comment: So you ant to select only those lines where parentid is null or parent.deleted<>'0'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you are looking for is

```
SELECT child.* 
FROM `content` child 
    LEFT JOIN 
        content parent 
 on parent.id=child.parentid AND child.submittype='2' 
WHERE child.username=? 
AND child.deleted='0' AND (parent.deleted='0' OR parent.deleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY child.id DESC LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$getitem = $connectdb->prepare("SELECT child.* FROM `content` child LEFT JOIN 
content parent ON parent.id=child.parentid AND child.submittype='2' WHERE child.username=? 
AND child.deleted='0' AND (parent.deleted='0' OR parent.deleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY child.id DESC LIMIT 12");
```

Also your left join can just say the target table to join to like this:

```
$getitem = $connectdb->prepare("SELECT child.* FROM `content` child LEFT JOIN 
parent ON parent.id=child.parentid AND child.submittype='2' WHERE child.username=? 
AND child.deleted='0' AND (parent.deleted='0' OR parent.deleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY child.id DESC LIMIT 12");
```

Lastly as a general rule I leave the on statement for the directions of the join, so the child.submittype could also be moved to the WHERE clause:

```
$getitem = $connectdb->prepare("SELECT child.* FROM `content` child LEFT JOIN 
parent ON parent.id=child.parentid WHERE child.submittype='2' AND child.username=? 
AND child.deleted='0' AND (parent.deleted='0' OR parent.deleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY child.id DESC LIMIT 12");
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows, even if `parentid` is NULL. The first step to solve your problem is therefore to use an `INNER JOIN` instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) for an explanation.

Your result set will now only include rows, where a parent is actually available. To filter this result further, your `WHERE` clause is already there. However, for better readability I suggest to move the filter on submittype there as well. The overall result will be:

```
SELECT child.* FROM `content` child INNER JOIN
  content parent on parent.id=child.parentid
WHERE 
  child.username=? AND 
  child.submittype='2'AND 
  child.deleted='0' AND 
  parent.deleted='0' 
ORDER BY child.id DESC LIMIT 12
```